# Python Django не отображает картинки модели на сайте

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, django-model

пишу свой учебный проект по django и столкнулся с такой проблемой которой не возникало раньше. Когда пытаюсь вывести картинку загруженную в экземпляр модели с помощью  она никак не хочет отображаться, при этом остальные поля модели отображаются корректно:
models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    time_create = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('ProductCategory', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="Категории")
    brand = models.ForeignKey('Brand', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="Бренд")
    photo_front = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/%Y/%m/%d/", verbose_name="Главное фото", blank=True)
    photo2 = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/%Y/%m/%d/", verbose_name="Фото 2", blank=True)
    photo3 = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/%Y/%m/%d/", verbose_name="Фото 3", blank=True)
    photo4 = models.ImageField(upload_to="photos/%Y/%m/%d/", verbose_name="Фото 4", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product', kwargs={'product_slug': self.slug})
```

test.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
{% for b in posts %}
<p>{{ b.title }}</p>
<img src="{{ b.photo_front.url }}">
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

в итоге получается такой вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот что выдает код в браузере:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И вот что говорит консоль:
Not Found: /media/photos/2023/03/16/616036_XJFF9_1152_001_100_0000_Light-Cotton-T-shirt-with-Gucci-Blade-print.jpg
Not Found: /media/photos/2023/03/16/623953_XDBBQ_4011_001_100_0000_Light-Regular-fit-washed-jeans.jpg
Not Found: /media/photos/2023/03/16/clipboard_image_bfd7cf0e7879207e.jpg

Вообщем я предполагаю что ошибка заключается в неправильном пути, однако я как мог проверял, и пытался исправить, ничего не помогает.
Вот фото папок:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у тебя установлена библиотека Pillow?

Comment: Установил, не помогло, та же проблема